# Create a "path" (for a maze) in a two-dimensional array - any algorihtm ideas?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have a 2-dimensional array which I want to use to create a maze.

Each value can be 0 or 1 where 0 means there is a wall and 1 means there is a room. And now I need an algorithm to create a "path" within that array.

For example the blank array looks like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

An example of a "path" would be:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

It basically comes down to this:

1) Everything is `0`

2) I have a random start point which will be a `1`

3) From that point I need to make random adjacent values `1`. BUT: There should never be a square of 4 or more adjacent fields being a `1` AND: I don't want a linear path, I want it to be a maze

(Not all the array has to be used for the maze. Infact it would be cool if I could say I want a certain amount (say 20 or 50) of rooms within that array)

Are there any good algorithms or ideas I could use for this (especially #3 of my list)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive backtracking procedure can do this.

```
algorithm gen-maze(pos):
    set pos to 1

    build a list of neighboring positions
    randomly shuffle this list
    for each neighbor n of pos in random order:
        if n is 0 and setting it to 1 doesn't create a square:
            gen-maze(n)
```

Start this algorithm from a random position.

For an explanation, read the [Wikipedia article about depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and be sure to watch the [animation](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3aMAZE_30x20_DFS.ogv).

Comment: Thank you, that works fine so far. Only one thing I still have trouble with: How to properly check if I would create a square?

Comment: Ok, I solved this by just counting how many adjacent rooms a potential new room would have before creating it (within the for-loop). This number must equal 1.